# Does the Lao visa on arrival at the Thai border require a full blank passport page for Australians?

Tags: visas, passports, borders, australian-citizens, laos

I'm an Australian citizen currently in Bangkok deciding where to travel (preferably overland) next.

I just read that for Cambodia I would need to get a full-page visa, but I only have three such pages left and I'm conserving them for when I really have to use them, like China and Mongolia.

I've read that for Laos I can get a visa on arrival when crossing the border and I need to provide a passport photo for it. The photo requirement makes it seem like it would be a full page visa but unlike the info I found for Cambodia, that is not specifically stated.

(Australian passports do not have the possibility of adding extra pages.)

Comment: You may not need a full page for Mongolia. I didn't.

Comment: I did require a full page for Mongolia (NZ citizen, 2 years ago)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that it needs a full page, I figured this out by searching for Laos visa photos in google. It always showed a full page visa except for older visas where it was a stamp. I guess you will end up with two empty pages :)

[image: Laos visa]

Comment: Might be time to look into the Philippines! (=

Comment: As of late last year, these are used at the border.   Don't know *specifically* for Aussies, but unless it's a special case, this is what you'd get.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what an Australian citizen receives as a visa-on-arrival as of September 2013. I can also state the fee is `USD` $10 + `USD` $1. If you don't have $1 you can pay `THB` 40 instead.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTICE**: As you can see from the below comments, the answer MeNoTalk gave is the correct one. You will need at least one page the for the Visa, and likely more space for the stamps as you can see on the second image below.

On google images you can find the same that MeNoTalk posted, but those types of visa are normally used by embassies, since they need to be stamped off later on arrival so you cannot use it multiple times. When you do visa-on-arrival, this is not needed, and a direct stamp with todays date does the trick. I would assume therefore that they simply stamp the passport instead of a sticker.

I found several different stamps online, some older such as this here:
[image]

And some newer such as this here:
[image]

On top of that [about.com mentions](http://goseasia.about.com/od/laos/a/laos_travel_requirements.htm) the visa-on-arrival to be a stamp.

Comment: The top image is the same as what I have, but this was obtained via a consulate, not at the border.

Comment: @Doc When was that?

Comment: I'm going to focus my answer to Australians going via the border in case those variables are important.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The first image is out of date, current Lao visas on arrival are full-page stickers.  The second image is of the arrival and departure stamps placed next to the VOA, not the visa itself.

Comment: Agree with @jpatokal, the page you linked actually mentions on the VOA section: "A blank page is required for the visa stamp."

Comment: @jpatokal thanks! Can you kindly confirm the answer above then, I will delete this one.

Comment: Yup, that looks like the visa on arrival I got when I last crossed into Laos via the Friendship Bridge in 2009.

Comment: Bummer this was going to be my plan today to take the chance and find out the true answer to kill two birds with one stone. But if I'm definitely losing a page I'm better off going back to Malaysia where AirAsia lives.

Comment: You're better off going back to Malaysia, where they also don't charge an entry fee.   If you don't care about actually entering (just 'flagpoling'), you could also go to a Burmese border with 10 crisp new USD (or 500 THB); borders such as Mae Sot (and Mae Sai) are open *just* for this (rumor is that they will open properly 'soon').   Burma uses single-slot stamps, not full-page.   Don't go to Lao unless you're ready to use the full month they give you; when you are ready, spend as little time as possible in Vientiane (just IMO).